# Firefox: Page Background Color *before it starts loading*

Tags: firefox

"browser.display.background_color" sets the background color of some pages (blank etc.).

However, If you open a link in a new tab - the color of the new page *before it starts loading* is not affected by that setting.

Set "browser.tabs.loadInBackground" to false and override New Tab to "about:blank".

Now open a link in a new tab.

I'd like to change that and I'd be glad if you could refer me to the relevant code in the source files.

Thank you.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2987189

Comment: Is there any side-effect to setting `browser.tabs.loadInBackground` to false?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code is in chrome\browser\content\browser\tabbrowser.css.

```
.tabbrowser-tabbox {
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml#tabbrowser-tabbox");
/*
  background: Menu;
  color: MenuText;
 */
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `browser.display.use_system_colors` to `false` in `about:config`, it uses the color of the Firefox theme on that brief interval before start loading a page. If the theme is dark, it will suffice to remove the white flash background if that is specifically what you want.